# Confused about React PrivateRoute Syntax {}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router-v4

I'm new to React. I'm working on react router now and saw many people use PrivateRoute component to handle user authentication pages. However, I'm so confused with the syntax and the understanding of this function.

```
export function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, authed, ...rest }) {
 return (
    <Route {...rest}
        render={
            (props) => authed ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to={{ pathname: 'login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
        }
    />
 )
}
```

And it's used like this below

```
< PrivateRoute authed={this.props.isAuthenticated} path="/profile" component={MyProfile} />
```

May I know why we wrap all the parameters inside {} like this { component: Component, authed, ...rest }?
and why we use "component: Component" like this? Is is for break component={MyProfile} ? But why we write like this?
what are the (props) and ...props?

...rest is path="/profile" and other arguments like 'exact' right?

Thank you so much!

Comment: do you need any more help with this question? Please let me know or mark my answer as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> May I know why we wrap all the parameters inside {} like this { component: Component, authed, ...rest }?

This is a JavaScript syntax known as destructuring assignment. It is an incredibly handy way of unpacking values from arrays and objects.

Imagine your function expects an object with the key of id. You write `function(myObject) { return myObject.id; }`. With destructuring you can write `function({id}) { return id; }`. And expect that the object passed will be destructured into the requested keys.

> what are the (props) and ...props?

First, the `...` is known is the spread operator. And its another handy shortcut of expanding an array or object into places where arguments or elements are expected.

Secondly, the `(props)` is part of an arrow function declaration. Notice that it is followed by an arrow: `(props) =>` . This is the same as writing `function(props)`. However, there are some subtle differences between arrow functions and the function keyword, mainly what the this keyword refers to.

Also note that `(props) =>` is followed by an implicit return. You can write an arrow function like this `(props) => { return true;}`, using an explicit return. Or an implicit return without brackets, like this: `(props) => true`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :D! May I know why we can use ':' in component:Component to replace component by Component here?

Comment: Yes, that is another feature of the destructuring assignment syntax. We can rename a key at the same time that we are destructuring it. So taking our example another step further, instead of ```function(myObject) { return myObject.id; }``` we can write ```function({ id: renamedId}) { return renamedId; }```

So in your code, the PrivateRoute component takes in a prop named component, it then destructures the component prop renaming it to capital ```Component``` at the same time. That way it can be rendered in the react element syntax: ```<Component```.

Answer (score 2):

> May I know why we wrap all the parameters inside {} like this { component: Component, authed, ...rest }?

This is JavaScript syntax, however, it is often a developer preference or coding style guide decision to write React function components in the way you described originally.  Let's break down your question further.

`component: Component`: this is a shorthand for destructuring a function argument (`component`) and assigning it to a new variable name (`Component`).  Note that we do this because React requires component names begin with a capital letter.

`...rest`: this is how we can handle any number of additional arguments passed to this function, known as rest parameters.  Think of it like: "collect all remaining function arguments into a value (`rest`) we can later use in a function.  In React this is very common to pass props down a component tree.

EDIT:

- [reactpatterns.com](https://reactpatterns.com/) has some useful and succinct examples.

References:

- [MDN-Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [MDN-Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [React Docs-JSX in depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

Comment: Thank you so much :D. So for the component:Component, when we use component={MyProfile}, we pass a prop named 'component' and the value of it is 'MyProfile', then in the function, component:Component is for changing the name of the variable from component to Component? May I have some examples of this kind of use?  Oh and I'm still not sure that why we need to destruct the props using {}, I feel we already just pass props seperately like path="/profile"  and authed={this.props.isAuthenticated} ...

Comment: I added a link with examples.  You don't NEED to do it this way, it is more of a pattern for writing components and consuming them in a consistent way.

Comment: Oh thank you so much! That's really helpful! :D Now I think I understand the {} and ...rest now! But still a bit confused about component:Component...what will happen if we just use component instead of component:Component here?

Comment: take a look at this https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized

Comment: ^ A bit off topic though, I always think Cap is a convention, turns out to be a requirement? What's the runtime impact if I break this rule?

Comment: Oh Thank you so much! So it looks like a requirement. And may I know what is this syntax component:Component as the first name will be replaced by the second name by using ':' in function params ?